# System.Net's Webclient in C# won't connect to server

Tags: c#, exception, webclient, system.net

Is there something I need to do to get System.Net working with Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition? I can't seem to get any web type controls or classes to work at all.. the below WebClient example always throws the exception "**Unable to connect to the remote server**".. and consequently I can't get the WebBrowser control to load a page either.

Here is the code (Edited):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
                string s = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
                this.textBox1.Text = s;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is in a simple form with only a textbox control (with multiline set to true) in it. The exception gets thrown on the `DownloadString(...)` line.  I also tried using `WebRequest`.. same exception!

EDIT:

I am connected to a Linksys WRT54G Router that connects directly to my cable modem. I am not behind a proxy server, although I did run `proxycfg -u` and I got:

```
Updated proxy settings
Current WinHTTP proxy settings under:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\
    SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections\
      WinHttpSettings :

 Direct access (no proxy server).
```

I am using Windows XP and not running any kind of firewall. Only AVG at the moment. I'm pretty sure I shouldn't have to forward any ports or anything, but I did try forwarding port 80 to my workstation on my router. Didn't help.

Answer (score 5):

(**update** - I meant `proxycfg`, not `httpcfg`; `proxycfg -u` will do the import)

First, there is nothing special about "express" here. Second, contoso is a dummy url.

What OS are you on? And do you go through a proxy server? If so, you might need to configure the OS's http stack - `proxycfg` will do the job on XP, and can be used to import the user's IE settings.

The sample is fine, although it doesn't correctly handle the multiple `IDisposable` objects - the following is much simpler:

```
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
            string s = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
            // do something with s
        }
```

Comment: I am on XP and not running through a proxy server.

Comment: Still, it might be worth trying `proxycfg -u`; also, do you have any aggressive firewall running? Try checking for any block/deny entries...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any firewall software on your PC that might be affecting it? Have you tried with any sites other than Google?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it with different sites, and no, I'm not running any kind of firewall software on my PC.